# How to get unique values in multidimensional array and add values per unique value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array.

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Sarah"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Sarah"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(5)  
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Aprelle"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Just"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Sarah"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Sarah"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(2)
  }
```

I want to get the every unique name and add every instance of collect value per unique name.

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Sarah"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(9)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Aprelle"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Just"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Sarah"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(5)
  }
```

So far, i can only get the names correctly. how can I add the collect value per name?

This is my code

```
    $stat = array ( 0 => array ( 'name' => 'Sarah', 'collect' => 4, ), 1 => array ( 'name' => 'Sarah', 'collect' => 5, ), 2 => array ( 'name' => 'Aprelle', 'collect' => 2, ), 3 => array ( 'name' => 'Just', 'collect' => 3, ), 4 => array ( 'name' => 'Sarah', 'collect' => 3, ), 5 => array ( 'name' => 'Sarah', 'collect' => 2, ), );


$datasetCount = count($stat); // returns count of array items of any array
echo "<h1>There are $datasetCount names</h1>"; 
$pname = "";
$pcollect = 0;

$i = 0; 
foreach ($stat as $each_name) { 
    $i++; 
    $storename = "";
    echo "<h2>Name $i</h2>"; 

    while (list($key, $value) = each ($each_name)) { 

    if($i == 1)
    {
        if($key == 'name')
        {
            $pname = $value;
            echo "<br/> Name: ".$pname."<br/>";
        }
        if($key == 'collect')
        {
            $pcollect = $value;
            echo "<br/> Collect: ".$pcollect."<br/>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($key == 'name')
        {
            if($pname != $value)
            {
                $pname = $value;
                $storename = $value;
                $check = 1;
                echo "<br/>".$storename."<br/>";
            }else
            {
                $check = 0;
                echo "<br/>".$storename."<br/>";
            }         
        } 

    }       

}
}
```

Output should be in this order:

```
Name:Sarah 
Collect: 9

Aprelle 
Collect: 2

Just 
Collect: 3

Sarah
Collect: 5
```

Check if the next name is the same with the first name, if yes, merge them. and check again if the next is the same.

Comment: Why do you use a loop over `$each_name`? Why not just `$pname = $each_name['name']` and `$pcollect = $each_name['collect']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
$newArr = array();

foreach($stat as $val) {
    if(isset($newArr[$val['name']])) {
        $newArr[$val['name']] += $val['collect'];
    } else {
        $newArr[$val['name']] = $val['collect'];
    }
}
```

and if you really need the format

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Sarah"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(9)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Aprelle"
    ["collect"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

then add:

```
$newArr2 = array();

foreach($newArr as $key=>$val) {
    $newArr2[] = array('name' => $key, 'collect' => $val);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Version that will add "collect" only if the current "name" is the same as the previous "name".

```
$newArr = array();

for($i = 0; $i<count($stat); $i++) {
    // check if $newArr has any values, it will be false only the first loop
    if(isset($newArr[key($newArr)]['name'])) {
        // check if the current value of the loop is the same as the last value in the new array
        if($stat[$i]['name'] == $newArr[key($newArr)]['name']) {
            // if it is, this means that we just have to add the current "collect" value to the last element of $newArr
            $newArr[key($newArr)]['collect'] += $stat[$i]['collect'];
        } else {
            // if not, we have to create a new value
            $newArr[] = array('name' => $stat[$i]['name'], 'collect' => $stat[$i]['collect']);
            // we have to go to the newly added value of the new array
            next($newArr);
        }
    } else {
        $newArr[] = array('name' => $stat[$i]['name'], 'collect' => $stat[$i]['collect']);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd end up with undefined index notices using this approach. You'll need to check if the named index exists before incrementing its value

Comment: this is close to what I want. I think the title of my post is misleading. What I want is to check unique name from before and after an element. for example, the output should be, sarah, aprelle, just, sarah. what i need is to check if the next to sarah is sarah again, if yes, they will merge and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier preparing your data before outputting it. You can just create a new array containing the relevant values using the following.

```php
$totals = [];
foreach($stat as $entry){
    if(!isset($totals[$entry['name']])){
        $totals[$entry['name']] = $entry['collect'];
    }else{
        $totals[$entry['name']] += $entry['collect'];
    }   
}

var_dump($totals);
```

Not having the collects indexed by name would mean that, if you wanted to display it on a per-name basis, you'd have to iterate over the entire list again for each name you'd want to show.

Edit: Your preferred output threw me off. Updated code to your expectations

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//array container
$data = array();

$data[] = array('name'=>'Sarah', 'collect'=>8);
$data[] = array('name'=>'Sarah1', 'collect'=>8);
$data[] = array('name'=>'Sarah', 'collect'=>8);
$data[] = array('name'=>'Sarah2', 'collect'=>8);
$data[] = array('name'=>'Sarah', 'collect'=>8);

//unique array container
$unique  =array();

foreach($data as $itemArray){

    //create new value in the array
    if(!isset($unique[$itemArray['name']])){
        $unique[$itemArray['name']] = $itemArray;
    }
    else{
        //sum the collect details
        $unique[$itemArray['name']]['collect'] +=  $itemArray['collect'];
    }
}

print_r(array_values($unique));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2-dimensional array indexed by names and collect values:

```
$unique = array();
foreach ($stats as $s) {
    if (isset($unique[$s['name']]) {
        $unique[$s['name']][$s['collect']] = $s;
    } else {
        $unique[$s['name']] = array($s['collect'] => $s);
    }
}
```

Then you can walk through this, collecting all the values at the same level:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($unique as $by_name) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $by_name);
}
```